# Why was this worse?

Tags: plot-explanation, 10-cloverfield-lane

In ***10 Cloverfield Lane***, at one point the air intake and filtration system stops or stalls. Howard says `this is bad`, because they will run out of air. Then he tries a ceiling hatch/door, and it won't open all the way. He says `this is worse`. They never address it again, even later in the film when they should have, plot wise.

### Why was that door not opening? Why didn't they clear it? Character wise, it would not make sense for Howard to leave it alone.

Comment: The title of your question says "Why was this worse?", but it in your commets to my answer, you ask another question. You may want to edit your title to reflect the information you're asking about.

Comment: @BenPlont I'd agree the title is a little cryptic and doesn't seem to reflect the actual question, but it seems to fit to the film. Anyway, at the end of the day we're still answering full questions here, not mere titles without reading the question body.

Comment: I assumed that it was a hatch to the room we see later. The reason it was worse is because it wouldn't open for some reason, so they had to go with plan-b: Shove the girl into the vent and hope she can get to the room another way.
They didn't ever explain why the door was blocked, and she apparently didn't unblock it since she had to use the same vent system later.